# Idle time in RTOS

Tags: rtos

Since idle tasks are generally used to safely consume CPU time that is not required by other software, what would happen if there was no idle task? Would the RTOS just automatically create one? Also, what other purpose do idle tasks serve other than consuming time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what would happen if there was no idle task? Would the RTOS just automatically create one?

I doubt there is any RTOS that would do that. If there would be no idle task, then the list of runnable tasks would be empty and the scheduler would probably crash. Generally the single most important reason for idle thread's existence is to make the list of runnable tasks "never empty". This simplifies the code of scheduler.

> Also, what other purpose do idle tasks serve other than consuming time?

In some systems idle task can perform some low priority activities (for example some garbage collection). It can also switch the core to low-power mode, especially on embedded devices. In that case when the idle task is run it means that there is nothing more to do, so the core can be stopped and wait for the next event (hardware interrupt or timeout) without using too much power. When the next event arrives the core is awakened by hardware and the event is processed. Either some "normal" thread will start running, or - if there is still nothing more to do - idle thread will resume and again switch to low-power mode.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the CPU clock is running, instructions must be executed; if there were no idle task, then your OS is broken. The idle loop is an intrinsic part of the RTOS, not a user task, so the RTOS does not need to "create one automatically".

A low priority user task that never yields will prevent the idle loop from running; which is not necessarily a good thing.  Such a task is not the same thing as the *idle loop*.  For one thing any CPU usage tools the RTOS supports would report 100% usage all the time if such a task eusted - execution of the idle loop is not included is CPU usage because the CPU is always ready to respond to any interrupt event when idle - the loop does not ever cause any ready task to be delayed.

The idle task, or "*idle loop*" is typically just that, and empty loop that the program counter is set to when there is nothing else to do.  In some architectures the loop may include a "wait-for-interrupt" instruction that stops core execution (stops clocking the core) to reduce power consumption.  Since any context switch necessarily requires an interrupt to occur, the processor can if WFI is supported just stop in this loop.

Some RTOS support user hooks for the idle loop; low-priority run-to-completion functions that can operate in the background in the idle loop context.

Answer (score 0):

what other purpose do idle tasks serve other than consuming time?
Most commonly, it does two things:
1. Garbage(resource) collection or cleaning
2. Initiate steps to reduce power consumption